# CSS - How to align 3 div with an image horizontally with equal size for each div

Tags: html, css

CSS - How to align 3 div with background image horizontally with equal size for each div?

I am using the below styles and 3 divs are displaying horizontally but I don't know how to split 3 div equally to occupy 100% width.

```
.div-1 {
 background: url('images/iamge1.jpg');
}
        
.div-2 {
 background: url('images/image2.jpg');
}
        
.div-3 {
 background: url('images/image3.jpg');
}
            
.div-1,
.div-2,
.div-3 {
 display: inline-block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -2):

```css
.div-1 {
    background: url('images/iamge1.jpg');
    background:yellow;
}
    
.div-2 {
    background: url('images/image2.jpg');
    background:red;
}
    
.div-3 {
    background: url('images/image3.jpg');
    background:green;
}
        
.div-1,
.div-2,
.div-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height:150px;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
}
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
  <div class="div-3"></div>
</div>
```

Please add `width:33.3333333333%` to each div & also add height because your div don't have height & add `display:flex` to parent container.
currently, I added height & background color because your image is the local image you can remove background color if it's working

Comment: Please check again, I made some changes